# npm debug upgrade issue when installing "npm install -g heroku"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, version

Everytime I run "npm install -g heroku" in my terminal I have this error pop up

```
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)

> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/heroku/bin/run
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/heroku
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/heroku/bin/run' -> '/usr/local/bin/heroku'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/heroku
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/peter/.npm/_logs/2021-01-05T19_51_17_072Z-debug.log
```

I have tried to update Debug version in the terminal but haven't been successful, any advice would be greatly appreciated. If you need me to provide more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar today and tried learning a bit more on this. Try removing Heroku first. Then go to your root by typing sudo su in terminal, enter password, check version for npm. Then check heroku --version. If nothing pops up download directly npm install -g heroku. Check version, then open a new terminal and check heroku --version. It should work at this point. Hope this points you in the right direction a bit.